# Expect Script working manually not via NiFi Processor

Tags: bash, sftp, apache-nifi, expect, nifi-processor

I have NiFi 1.23.2 running in cluster mode in K8s. As List SFTP does not take an incoming request have written a script that is called from ExecuteStreamCommand to count the number of files in an SFTP directory.
I am using expect to make this happen.

```
#!/bin/sh -e


USER=$1
export PASSWORD="${SFTP_PASSWORD}"
REMOTE_DIR=$3
HOST=$4

BATCH_FILE=$(mktemp)
echo "spawn sftp $USER@$HOST" > $BATCH_FILE
echo "expect \"*fingerprint*\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
echo "send \"yes\\r\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
echo "expect \"password:\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
echo "send \"\$env(PASSWORD)\\r\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
echo "expect \"sftp>\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
echo "send \"ls -l $REMOTE_DIR \\r\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
echo "expect \"sftp>\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
echo "send \"exit\\r\"" >> $BATCH_FILE

#expect $BATCH_FILE

dirs=$(expect $BATCH_FILE|  sed -n '/sftp>/, /sftp>/p' | grep -v '^sftp>'| awk '$0 ~ /^d/ {print $NF}')
rm $BATCH_FILE
total=0

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
directories=($dirs)
IFS=$SAVEIFS


for value in "${directories[@]}"; do
       val=$(echo "$value" | tr -d '[:blank:]' | tr -d '[:space:]')
       if [[ "$val" == "Completed" || "$val" == "Failed" || "$val" == "Rejected" || "$val" == "Error" ]]; then
           dir=$REMOTE_DIR/$val
           BATCH_FILE=$(mktemp)
           echo "spawn sftp $USER@$HOST" > $BATCH_FILE
           echo "expect \"*fingerprint*\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
           echo "send \"yes\\r\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
           echo "expect \"password:\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
           echo "send \"\$env(PASSWORD)\\r\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
           echo "expect \"sftp>\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
           echo "send \"ls -l $dir\\r\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
           echo "expect \"sftp>\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
           echo "send \"exit\\r\"" >> $BATCH_FILE
           count=$(expect $BATCH_FILE|  sed -n '/sftp>/, /sftp>/p' | grep -v '^sftp>'| wc -l)
           total=$((total + count))
           rm $BATCH_FILE
       fi
done

echo "$total"
```

This script is working fine when I run inside this manually with in the container, also is working fine when NiFi runs on standalone mode in 1.23.0

```
bash-4.4$ ./test_files.sh
4
```

*test_files.sh has the same script but HOST, USER and REMOTE_DIR hardcoded.*

When I call the same script from NiFi processor I am getting

```
execution.error
send: spawn id exp3 not open while executing "send "yes\r"" (file "/tmp/tmp.eatmyc06B6" line 3)
```

[image]

The fingerprint expect had to be added inside the container as it is being asked. when running outside NiFi it is not required.

**Configuration for ExecuteStreamCommand**
[image]

There are times when it works, in this screen grab, one has correct output the other doesn't

[image]

**correct output:**

[image]

**Error and Incorrect output**

[image]
I have tried the header with both /bash and /sh.

what could be the reason? Please advise.

Comment: @pynexj: that gave me this 
bash-4.4$ ./test_files.sh

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "*fingerprint*"? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "yes\r" to { exp0 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "password:"? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "Qwerty@123\r" to { exp0 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "sftp>"? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "ls -l /files/Temp \r" to { exp0 }
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "sftp>"? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "exit\r" to { exp0 }
0

but the wrong output

Comment: but without exp_internal 1, I was getting the expected output (4)

Comment: Thank you.
Turns out there is a workaround, there is an option to  change the first processor to execute in single node, this will execute flowfiles from single node.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a workaround, there is an option to change the first processor to execute in single node, this will execute flowfiles from single node.

[image]
[image]
[image]